# How to view Pycharm's Run command so I can copy it into Jenkins

Tags: pycharm, pytest

I have a test that Pycharm runs with Pytest and it builds/runs successfully ...  Awesome.

But I'm trying to run the same test in Jenkins and I'm having trouble getting the test to run successfully there.

So I was hoping I could cheat and steal the pytest run command from Pycharm and slap it into Jenkins.  Is this possible?

Comment: Every OS allows to see the full command a process was started with, therefore you just have to open a process viewer tool and extract that command while the unit test are running.

Comment: Pycharm uses its own testrunner, so you won't be able to get the exact same output as running on the command line. Better you run `pytest` on the command line yourself and get it running here. Mostly this kind of problem is related to the Python path.